# Ошибка при создании screen

Tags: php, linux, ssh, gnu-screen

Здравствуйте. Есть скрипт на PHP ,который выполняет команду `screen -S test337` через SSH ,вот он:

```
/* Соединение */
$connect = ssh2_connect($rows1['ip'], $rows1['sshport']);
ssh2_auth_password($connect, $rows1['login'], base64_decode($rows1['password']));
$shell = ssh2_shell($connect);

/* Выполнение команды */
fwrite($shell, 'screen -S test337'.PHP_EOL);

/* Получение ответа */
$text = '';
while($buf = fread($shell,4096)) {$text .= $buf;};
echo '<br>'.$text;

/* Закрытие соединения */
fclose($shell);
```

В переменой `$rows1` хранятся данные от SSH.
Но сервер выдаёт ошибку:

```
Cannot find terminfo entry for 'vanilla'
```

Если даже отправить просто команду `screen` ,он вернёт точно такую же ошибку.
На сервере стоит CentOS 6.*
Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно исправить?
И из-за чего это вообще может происходить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

исправить ошибку можно, установив переменной окружения `TERM` какое-нибудь более распространённое (а значит, с большей вероятностью присутствующее в целевой системе) значение. например, *xterm*, или даже *vt100*.

дополните вызов программы `screen` таким присвоением значения переменной TERM:

```
TERM=xterm screen ...
```

или таким:

```
TERM=vt100 screen ...
```